# Find vectors $x_1, ... , x_k$ such that $D_n = Int(x_1, ... , x_k)$

Tags: vectors, vector-lattices

> The following set of points is a lattice in $\mathbb{R}^n$:
>
> $D_n =$ {$(v_1, ... , v_n)| v_1, ... , v_n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $v_1 + ... + v_n$ is even}
>
> Find vectors $x_1,...,x_k$ such that $D_n = Int(x_1, ..., x_k)$

My solution:

Firstly, I know that if $x_1, ..., x_k \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then we define
$Int(x_1,...,x_k) = t_1x_1 + ... + t_kx_k$ where $t_1,...,t_k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

So, I have deduced that the vectors $x_1, ..., x_k \in \mathbb{R}^n$ so that $D_n = Int(x_1, ..., x_k)$ are any vectors such that $t_1x_1 + ... + t_kx_k = (v_1, ..., v_n)$ where $v_1+...+v_n$ are even.

However, I feel my solution is certainly lacking and I was wondering if anyone could help guide me in the right direction.

Thank you.

Comment: You haven't stated what the $x_i$'s are.

Comment: They are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: So you're saying that any choice works? What about $x_1=x_2=\cdots =x_k=0$? The question says "Find vectors ...".

Comment: I think we are looking for a more general solution

Answer (score 1):

$D_n$ is known as the checkerboard lattice and a basis for it is

$\begin{align}
{\bf x}_1 &= \begin{bmatrix}
           -1 \\
           -1 \\
             0\\
           \vdots \\
           0
         \end{bmatrix},
\end{align}$
$\begin{align}
{\bf x}_2 &= \begin{bmatrix}
           1 \\
           -1 \\
           0 \\
           \vdots \\
           0
         \end{bmatrix},
\end{align}$
$\begin{align}
{\bf x}_3 &= \begin{bmatrix}
           0 \\
           1 \\
          -1 \\
           0 \\
           \vdots \\
           0
         \end{bmatrix},
\end{align}$
$\cdots ,$
$\begin{align}
{\bf x}_n &= \begin{bmatrix}
           0 \\
            \vdots \\
           0\\
           1 \\
          -1
         \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}$